# 301 redirect with RegEx

Tags: regex, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've searched for the right expression here and can't seem to find it. I need to rewrite dozens of URLs and would like to use regex to 301 redirect all to a single page.

The current pages are all something like:

www.example.com/2008/07/garbage.html/this-is-what-i-want

www.example.com/2005/09/moregarbage.html/this-is-what-i-want

and I want to slice everything out of the middle and take both pages to

www.example.com/this-is-what-i-want

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you give an example of one of the things you've tried to resolve this already?

Comment: What web server? Server side script language? Javascript redirects?

Comment: I'm using the Redirection tool in wordpress to implement the redirects. I've tried several different redirection variants to get this to work. I tried one (i forget what it was) that made it www.mydomain.com/this-is-what-i-want/2008/07/garbage.html and then ^/this-is-what-i-want/(.+)$ but nothing works and I'm ending up with 404s no matter what i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main WP .htaccess you can use this rewrite rule just below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\d{4}/.*/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava, what does in \d{4}/, the expression I'm matching that I intend to keep?

Comment: `\d{4}` matches year part at the start. The part that we are keeping is last `([^/]+)` one. Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after posting the comment--I did and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want everything removed from the first / to the last / ...

I don't know what language you are working in, but something like this would work as a regular expression to just match what you wanted to match.

((https?://)?[^/]+)/.+(/[^/]+)

The first and third match groups contain the parts you want... e.g., in Python:

```
import re
str = 'http://www.example.com/test/this.com/this-is-what-I-want'
regexp = r'((https?://)?[^/]+)/.+(/[^/]+)'
match = re.match(regexp, str)
print match.group(1) + match.group(3)
```

Yields:

```
$ python t.py
http://www.example.com/this-is-what-I-want
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. So I could make the string ^/this-is-what-I-want and it should work for any "stuff" before it, right?

Comment: I see someone answered WP specifically. :)